# LED brightness control with limit and LDR

Tags: ldr

I made a digital circuit that follows the signal of an LDR, setting on a LED when the voltage is grater than the limit. It also changes the intensity of the brightness as the voltage rises and fall, above the limit.

So I'm looking for how to do the same with an analog circuit, easily. I want to use 5 V. In the search I found circuits that:

a) Turn off or on an LED with a level;

b) Control the brightness of am LED.

But not one that do both. Can you suggest any example? MOSFET? Comparator? Operational amp? Which Is the better way?

[image: The signal that I want in the LED]

Comment: I have littles plants that need more light. So I want the LED tunrs on following the sun.

Comment: It is probably going about high power Leds so best way is to go with PWM. Do a ramp generator 0-10V about 10kHz and compare this ramp with sensor voltage scaled to 0-10V also. The sensor signal has to be inverted since you need more Led light when sun goes down.

Comment: Your question is missing some details.  LED part number and link to datasheet?  Is 5 V the power source for the entire circuit including the LED(s), of the voltage level for the transition from off to on?  If it is the system power voltage, what is the voltage level for the on/off transition?  Depending on the answers, this probably can be done with one opamp and one transistor.  No PWM needed.

Comment: I'll just add that I don't even know what you want. You don't want only one of those two things in your list, you want `both`. But that's where everything stops. I've no idea ***precisely*** the behavior you actually do want. And keeping in mind the high non-linearity of an LDR and similar non-linearity of human brightness perceptions and gosh-only knows the needs of `little plants`, there's nothing there to know what the `right thing` should actually be and, if control knobs are needed, exactly what those knobs should do for you. I think there's missing `knowledge`. Oh, well.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Led to be completely off when sunlight is too much I would do it according picture below.

So ramp in range 0-8V and sensor signal range 0-10V (without inversion). If sensor is at 9V no pwm pulses go to mosfet(led completely off). If sensor is at 4V a 50% duty goes to mosfet.

[image]